# How to change the value of first row to its row number in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I have multiple excel sheets to be imported into R. I used the following code

```
files <- list.files(path = "D:/xxx/Daily Report/", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)

tbl <- sapply(files, read_xlsx, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows(.id = "S No")
```

In the S No column, the values that are filled is the file path. I want to convert them into the row number. Getting the following output when I try to change the value of `S No`

```
tbl <- tbl %>% mutate(.$`S No` = row_number())
Error: unexpected '=' in "tbl <- tbl %>% mutate(.$`S No` ="
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```r
tbl <- sapply(files, read_xlsx, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows %>% mutate(.id = 1:n() )
```

You could also change `.id` to what ever other column name you could want for it.

And using the intended function for this, thanks to OP and commentor below, @Gregor Thomas:

```r
tbl <- sapply(files, read_xlsx, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows %>% mutate(.id = row_number() )
```

Comment: `.id = row_number()` is a little more direct ;)

Comment: definitely! ill add it instead of removing my current answer, thanks